# Set full response size using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Using Spring MVC, for each incoming request id like to set the `statusCode` and `headers`.

Once they are set, I need to pad the response body to make the entire response size, including all headers and content (actual data wired to the client), to be exactly X bytes (e.g. 300 bytes). The response size will vary per request, but all responses will have to padded.

There are no limitations regarding the manipulation of the response.

Using `HttpServletResponse` I can set the `statusCose` and `headers` and also maybe get the response size. But I couldn't find a way to set the body content/length in accordance to the required size.

If I use a `ResponseEntity` I can set the body but can't tell the size of the response.

How can I pad the response to the required size while setting the fields above?

Comment: Your question is lacking some important inputs: 200KB including headers or body only?  Can you manipulate the string body and trim it as needed before setting it in the response entity?

Comment: @YaOg the answer to both is yes. I was under the impression that the question had that information, but I'll clarify.

Comment: Hmm, if I correctly understand what you ask, you want to know the *total* size of a response (headers + body). The application has full control for the body part, but the headers are normally processed by the servlet container. And you are right, the servlet specification has no provision for letting the application know about that part. A fixed total size is a rather uncommon requirement. Could you explain why you need that ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta the 300B is an exmaple. The response size will change per request, but is determined and will always require some padding. This is a requirement from the client side.

Comment: I'd say that the client side is completely broken if it expects every possible HTTP response to be of a given size. Why doesn't it conform to the HTTP protocol? I'd fix the client rather than breaking the server side to conform to a broken client.

Comment: @JBNizet I realize this sounds funny, but that's what we're looking for. If the client doesn't get the size it expects it will behave differently. Think of it as an MD5 check on the response size.

Comment: The correct control would be to set a Content-Length header, and only control the *body* size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as JB Nizet said, this requirement is fully outside of the HTTP protocol and you'd better fix the client side to only control the size of the body part (what the content-length header is made for).

Now assuming you really need to do that, I can imagine 2 ways to fulfil this requirement (both of them seem equally ugly...):

#### Use a dedicated proxy to post-process the HTTP response

Consistently add a custom header to the response that indicates the total size the response should have. Put a dedicated proxy between the clients and the server. That proxy should listen on its own port and forward everything to the server. For the response part, it should:

- read the header part line by line (delimited with `\r\n`), store the required total size without transmitting it and forward all other headers storing the number of bytes sent
- once the header part is over (empty line), read the body part and trunk or pad it to the correct size before transmitting it.

This would be a low level program that should use directly the socket interfaces, or that could directly be written in C. This really looks like plumbing, but it should be usable even for different servlet containers.

#### Compute the body part size and guess the header one

Control how your servlet container processes headers. The protocol requires that they are written as `NAME=value\r\n` and that the header part is followed by an empty line (`r\n`). But you should control twice whether the containers adds its own headers or whether it automatically adds some headers if you do not provide them. That should allow you to compute the header size from the headers you added to the response, but is clear coupled to a single servlet container, and when used the same way.

Alternatively, you could try to ask the response what headers it contains. Normally (at least Tomcat does it), it actually computes the header part when it commits the response (*). So you could:

- set the status and the headers you need
- commit the response by a call to `flushBuffer()`
- get the generated headers through:

  ```
  for (String name: resp.getHeaderNames()) {
      for (String value: resp.getHeaders(name)) {
          ...
  ```

If you take care of the status line (should be `HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n` but here again control twice its actual size), it should be enough to compute the total header size. Provided you have enough control on the body to know what you want to write, you should be able to compute how much padding you need.

This avoids a dedicated proxy, but it can only be guaranteed to work on a (version of a) particular servlet container

(*) **Beware**: when you commit the response manually, the servlet container can add a `Transfer-Encoding=chunked` header because it cannot guess the body size. Whether it is acceptable for you use case or not, I cannot know...

Comment: While I was hoping for a strict method, I have opted for your second solution, as it's simple and good enough for our requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the comment discussion above, you could create an [HttpResponse Wrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html).
Using your wrapper you can then intercept the response and override the actual size.

More info: your response wrapper writes response content to an internal byte array. It is not actually written to the "real" http output stream. In the filter you make sure 'write' and 'flush' called on the wrapper don't exceed your preferred max length.

Having said this, I agree with @jb-nijet that this is not common and looks like a flaw.